# Win10 doesn't boot

Tags: boot, boot-issues, windows, windows-iot

Yesterday I tried to install new insider version of win10 Iot for my raspberry, after that or it's just a coincidence my raspberry cannot boot any(RTM or insider preview version). The red light is constantly bright, yellow one wink few times and then it stay off. My display does show nothing. I use hdmi to vga converter. Core Watcher **see** the PI.

BOOTING RASPBIAN WORKS FINE.

- I tried to change sdcard: -GoodRAM 8GB 10class -GOODRAM 16GB 10class -Samsung 32Evo
- I tried 2 different phone charger: - lg 5V 1.8A - lg 5V 1.2A
- I tried also 2 different cable.

Sorry if my english made u cry. Regards Krystian.

edit:

- uart output:
- UART0
- UEFI firmware (version  built at 16:29:15 on Sep 22 2015)

Comment: Which model are you using?

Comment: @Jacobm001 2 model B 1GB

Comment: Might it be a faulty build? Try to re-install Win10 on your Card.

Comment: @Christian I did it hundred times. i also gone to my local store and i bought a new card with windows already installed.

Comment: What display adapter are you using?

Comment: I cant tell u know becouse iam not in home right now, but it doesnt boot without this converter plug in also. So i gues it is not the converter problem.isn it?

Comment: Sounds like a Display problem. Try using HDMI out to HDMI widescreen monitor/TV - Maybe something strange with the convertor?

Comment: Hdmi to hdmi and nothing. Not only when i boot windows but also when i boot rasbian now... But rasbian is kind of booted so i can connect by ssh normally. Looks like problem with hdmi on my board.

Comment: Yea definitely sounds like it. Since its booted and you can SSH. Send it back and get a replacement.

Comment: @KrystianKuśmierek I was trying to have vnc alone mode( while disabling hdmi from boot ), but unfortunately got my hdmi port permanently disabled(not sure how I did. lol). So make sure, you haven't done anything stupid like me before ordering a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the list of supported Sd cards  [here (click other hardware)](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/SupportedInterfaces.htm) and use one of them. I found that unless I use a supported SD card it sometimes does not boot correctly.  The latest IOT core seems to do a better job too.  Here is a link:  [IoT Core Setup](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/GetStarted.htm).  Try using the latest core tool to create your sd card image and it might work on your current class 10 micro sd card.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the card is not supported or the ISO is broken, try to use the ISO from UPP DUMP